# How to specify fields returned on table join

Tags: mysql

After a lot of help, finally got this [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/36) working.

I now can't figure out how to only return first and last name fields in the result ie: form_id's 2 and 3 from second table.

Is this possible even?

Comment: It it was me, I'd start from here... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you wanna this?

```
 SELECT c.name , c.custom_message , d.log_id , c.price , c.quantity , 
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=2 then d.value end) AS first_name , 
       GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=3 then d.value end) AS last_name 
 FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents c 
 JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data d ON d.log_id = c.purchaseid 
 WHERE c.name LIKE '%%' 
GROUP BY d.log_id 
ORDER BY c.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/90

Comment: erm .. not really.  What I'm after is .. as it was .. but only returning the first and last names per log_id, and not the email address and telephone number ie: pull in form ids 2 and 3 but not 9 and 18

Comment: so I'm after the same concatinated field in the result but with only those two fields returned. The idea being to hide personal details like email and phone number from the result

Comment: That's so nearly there! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/61, but as you say, multiple results per for_id. So, sorry to have to ask, but how do I aggregate them?

Comment: sorry - I think I've messed up the syntax at that fiddle, so it's all gone bit haywire.  Any chance you could jot down the complete query for me

Comment: which fiddle are we looking at now?

Comment: in my answer , this fiddle im looking in i have puted now in my answer

Comment: Got it: this works! Thank you --- SELECT c.name
     , c.custom_message
     , d.log_id
     , c.price
     , c.quantity
     , GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=2 then d.value end) AS first_name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=3 then d.value end) AS last_name
  FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents c
  JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data d
    ON d.log_id = c.purchaseid 
 WHERE c.name LIKE '%%'
 GROUP BY d.log_id 
 ORDER BY c.name

Comment: @user3321063 i added it as answer so you can accept it as solved :)

Comment: only sorry I have to keep quizzing you guys, but I am learning, slowly!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression to filter for specific form fields. As far as the SQL syntax knows you can get multiple results for each `form_id`, so you'll have to aggregate them:

```
 , GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=2 then d.value end) AS first_name
 , GROUP_CONCAT(case when d.form_id=3 then d.value end) AS last_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late answer but what if you try like below

```
SELECT c.name
     , c.custom_message
     , d.log_id
     , c.price
     , c.quantity
     ,(select GROUP_CONCAT(value)
from wp_wpsc_submited_form_data
where value like '%name%' and log_id = d.log_id)
AS VALUE
  FROM wp_wpsc_cart_contents c
  JOIN wp_wpsc_submited_form_data d
    ON d.log_id = c.purchaseid
 WHERE c.name LIKE '%%'
 GROUP BY d.log_id 
 ORDER BY c.name
```

You can use the same fiddle you have provided; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4bff/92

Comment: Three working answers!! Too much great help! Thanks guys. I'm now trying to work out how to mark Q as resolved ...

Comment: below the voting up/down arrow, there will be a tick mark button alike, click on that to accept the answer. Also, don't forget to vote up the answers :)

Comment: Cheers - I can't vote up the answers though - not high enough reputation